# How to store D3.js pie chart in database directly

Tags: javascript, database, d3.js, pie-chart

I copied and past a D3.js based Pie Chart example code from oreilly eBook. I modified it so that I can put data in run time. Its working absolutely fine.

But now I am facing a problem as I want to save this code with my own data in my database. But i am not getting it to how to do this. I search it over the internet but i did not get any thing.

If you have any suggestion then it would be help for me.

This is a link of oreilly book pie chart code.
http://jsbin.com/acatof/3/edit?html,output

Comment: If you store the dataset values used to construct the chart, you can reconstruct the chart whenever you like ...

Comment: Thanks for reply but But how?

Comment: Yes,I can put data in run time and also store that data to database. But the problem is how can i use it again.